# Magento admin - how to create download link to direct file?

Tags: magento

I have a PDF file that has been generated in ./var/label/somefile.pdf that I want to provide access to in the shipment area of Magento (specific to an order) as a link, but I am not sure what path to provide for the  tag. The preference would be for the link when clicked to start downloading the file to the browser and I only want this link accessible to someone that has been logged into admin.

I've attempted the direct path (http://domain.com/var/label/somefile.pdf) which fails with access error as it should and by trying different versions of getVarDir() to no avail.

Files hacked: sales/order/shipment/view/form.phtml

Comment: Can you give more description ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the visitor is logged into admin you need to pass by a Magento controller.

*I assume you know the basis about development with Magento or, at worst, can be helped by someone knowing.*

First of all, edit (or create, but you'll also need to create the route) a controller extending **Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action** and add a new method action **downloadShipmentPdf**

```
const SHIPMENT_PDF_BASE_DIRECTORY = "/var/www/magentorootfolder/var/label/";

public function downloadShipmentPdfAction() {
    $pdfName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('pdf',false);
    if ($pdfName) {
        $pdfContent = file_get_contents(SHIPMENT_PDF_BASE_DIRECTORY . $pdfName . '.pdf')
        if ($pdfContent) {
            $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($pdfContent);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can generate the admin-compliant URL for your PDF by calling

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("modulename/controllername/downloadShipmentPdf", array('pdf' => 'thepdfnamewithoutextension');
```